# How to create only time in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, timestamp, format

I have a time column in my dataframe, its format is character:

```
TIME
10:54:10.23
10:54:11.58
10:56:34.21
11:57:11.23
```

So u see I also have milliseconds in the end, but I try to get only `%H-%M-%S` without the .x milliseconds. I tried to creat a new column by: `data$hms <- format(as.POSIXct(data$TIME), "%H:%M:%S")` but failed... `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...):  String is not in a unique standard format`.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the miliseconds?

Comment: No I want to delete them completely, not just hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `times` from `chron` package after removing the last two digits with `str_remove`

```
#install.packages("chron")
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(TIME = chron(times=str_remove(TIME, '\\..*$')))
```

output:

```
  TIME    
  <times> 
1 10:54:10
2 10:54:11
3 10:56:34
4 11:57:11
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(TIME = c("10:54:10.23", "10:54:11.58", "10:56:34.21", 
                        "11:57:11.23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the milliseconds from the time.

```
df <- transform(df, TIME = sub('\\..*', '', TIME))
df
#      TIME
#1 10:54:10
#2 10:54:11
#3 10:56:34
#4 11:57:11
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$TIME <- trimws(df$TIME, whitespace = "\\.\\d+")
```

-output

```
df$TIME
[1] "10:54:10" "10:54:11" "10:56:34" "11:57:11"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(TIME = c("10:54:10.23", "10:54:11.58", "10:56:34.21", 
"11:57:11.23")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```